# How do I make the Android Web View's loadUrl NOT load from cache when content is expired?

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm confused with the default behaviour of the `loadUrl()` method on the Android Web View (Chrome 30). It never checks the source if it's cached! Basically I *have* to call `reload()` to make it actually check if the content is updated on the server. This is fundamentally different from the Chrome browser app (or any other browser I know of).

Why is this so? How can I make `loadUrl` actually perfrom a timestamp comparison to the server to see if the cached data is expired?

I've checked the cache mode and it is -1 (`WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT`). From the documentation, the behaviour is supposed to be how I expected it to be, but clearly is not:

> Default cache usage mode. If the navigation type doesn't impose any
>   specific behavior, use cached resources when they are available and
>   not expired